# SQL Server, DATEDIFF result in different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Could you please help me with question related to the `datediff` function?

I should move return result in new rows, based on count of hours. 
here example of table:

```
declare @t table (recid int,datefrom smalldatetime, dateto smalldatetime, diff int) 
insert into @t values (1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 0.2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, datediff (MINUTE,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 0.2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
insert into @t values (2,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 0.4, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,datediff  (MINUTE,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 0.4, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
insert into @t values (3,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 0.5, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,datediff  (MINUTE,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 0.5, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
insert into @t values (4,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,datediff  (MINUTE,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
select * from @t
```

Return result should be in next format:

```
recid datefrom              dateto              TimeStamp           ToNewHourMinutes
1     2015-12-30 08:44:00   2015-12-30 13:32:00 2015-12-30 08:44:00 16
1     2015-12-30 08:44:00   2015-12-30 13:32:00 2015-12-30 09:00:00 60
1     2015-12-30 08:44:00   2015-12-30 13:32:00 2015-12-30 10:00:00 60
1     2015-12-30 08:44:00   2015-12-30 13:32:00 2015-12-30 11:00:00 60
1     2015-12-30 08:44:00   2015-12-30 13:32:00 2015-12-30 12:00:00 60
1     2015-12-30 08:44:00   2015-12-30 13:32:00 2015-12-30 13:32:00 28
...
```

Many thanks for help.

Comment: Unclear, from where comming Minutes? From where this row: `2015-12-30 11:00    60`?

Comment: Seriously who added this question to favorites?

Comment: this should be as  a return result. for example i have a range (between two datetimes). question was how to split this result in some count of rows.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear whence is the `datetime` column which appears in your result set.  However, if your question is how to get minutes until the next hour, the `DATEPART()` function will come in handy:

```
SELECT datetime, 60 - DATEPART(minute, datetime) AS Minutes
FROM your_table
```

Comment: Result should be in serveral rows. for example 2015-12-30 10:25 datepart for is 35 minutes (your feedback it right), but how I can split result between '2015-12-30 10:25' and '2015-12-30 12:40' in different rows?

Comment: Oh...that's what you want.  You want a sort of pivot from the original two column table.

Comment: It might help to show us what the actual original table looks like.

Comment: It is not clear whence the timestamp column is coming.  Please show us a clear reproducible sample of your input table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know If is that what you need, but you can try something like:

```
declare @datefrom datetime
declare @dateto datetime
declare @minutes int
declare @temptime datetime
set @datefrom = '2015-12-30 10:25'
set @dateto = '2015-12-30 12:40'
select @temptime = @datefrom
select @minutes = 60 - datepart(minute, @temptime)
create table #temp
(
    [date] datetime,
    Minutes INT
)
while (datediff(minute,@temptime,@dateto)) > 60
begin
insert into #temp
select @temptime, @minutes

select @temptime = dateadd(hh,1,convert(char(14),@temptime,121)+'00:00') 
select @minutes = 60 - datepart(minute, @temptime)
end
insert into #temp 
select @dateto, 60 - datepart(minute, @dateto)

select * from #temp

drop table #temp
```

**OUTPUT**

```
date                    Minutes
2015-12-30 10:25:00.000 35
2015-12-30 11:00:00.000 60
2015-12-30 12:40:00.000 20
```